# Setup bisectBatchOnFunctionError=true for AWS Kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to configure `bisectBatchOnFunctionError=true` at AWS UI on top of Kinesis stream.

I didn't see any checkbox that related to that.

Can someone help me how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it from the lambda console. Go to your lambda function > click on add trigger > Select your kinesis stream > Click on additional settings > enable "Split batch on error".

You can not edit a kinesis trigger/event source mapping from the AWS console once its created. So you will have to create a new one.